# Telerik Reporting run javascript functions

Tags: javascript, telerik, telerik-reporting

We are currently loading a Telerik Report within a Radwindow.  We're trying to run javascript functionality within the report, but can't seem to find a way to hook in the script after the report loads:

```
$("#TelerikReportviewer").on("click", function () {
            ResetSessionTimer();
        });
```

Is there a way to load Javascript within the report when it loads on the page?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $("#reportViewer1")
            .telerik_ReportViewer({
                serviceUrl: 'api/Reports',
                templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.1.15.731.html',
                reportSource: {
                    report: "Payroll.ReportLibrary.HDMF.HDMF,Payroll.ReportLibrary",
                    parameters: {
                        payoutUID: '588206E1-BE66-4C6C-8433-0D51F7530ECF',
                        employeeTypeUID: '4DA38CC9-8C80-47A7-B020-FC296C029682,4DA38CC9-8C80-47A7-B020-FC296C029681',
                        group: 'Group By Department'
                    }
                },
                viewMode: 'PRINT_PREVIEW',
                scaleMode: '4.0',
                //scaleMode: 'FIT_PAGE',
                pageReady: function (e) { console.log("this event handler was attached in the constructor", e); },
                renderingEnd: function (e, args) { console.log("This event handler will be called before rendering the report.", e, args); }
            });
    });
</script>
```